# Writing 3 different matrices of different sizes column wise to a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, file-io, multiple-columns

How can I write three different matrices of different sizes say A, B and C using C?

The doubt being that once a particular row is printed the cursor is in the bottom most position, now how do we bring it back up?

Comment: It's easy if you first write the sizes of the matrices.

Comment: What exactly is the problem about the cursor moving to the bottom most position? Sounds like something that one would want to take place after printing a row. How exactly do you want the matrices printed? Please show it in your question. If the sizes are too large, then use a smaller example. Show your code and indicate your technical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. you plan in advanced the rows and then print each row (one you go down - you can't go up....)

If you can't handle the logic - use a 2d array to store everything and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fouth matrix D which contains A,B and C and write that matrix into a file.